# adding a control (ActiveX or not) to a chart (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, forms, charts, controls

I cannot find how to control a listbox I have added to a Excel Chart i.e. add/delete/select/unselect items and run macros accordingly.  I understand it is easier if the chart is embedded in a worksheet however I would very much like to do that on a separate sheet.  Thanks.
Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Pivot chart or chart linked to table that has a slicer?  https://www.contextures.com/pivotchart.html

Comment: the chart data are fed by VBA calculations (arrays). I just don't see how I can access  the listbox in VBA, in this particular case of a chart as a separate tab.

Comment: Please include your code and explain what isn't working with it. Do you need to control via vba? I was imagining you use a pivotchart and slicer and have macros associated with your pivottable update event.

Comment: Here is a sample spreadsheet :https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8jcl7vyu56f6g3/Book1.xlsm?dl=0
I don't know how to fill the listbox with the series names (VBA preferably), then be able to select which series I would like to display.

Comment: Relevant code should be in the question. You can [edit] it in.

Comment: To be honest, i don't even know where to start so there is no code to show. My issue is how to access the ListBox object in VBA.

Comment: https://www.contextures.com/excelvbalistboxcreate.html

Comment: Thank you. Does that however work the same if the listbox is on a chart as a separate sheet (i.e. not embedded in a worksheet) ?

Comment: List boxes are not part of charts AFAIK. I still think you possibly want a slicer or pivotchart and use link subs via the associated pivottable update event.

Comment: Exactly.  Yet I could add one (see Book1.xlsm sample), so that listbox should be accessible somewhere ???

Answer (score 0):

Even though the listbox is on the chart sheet, you should use some worksheet space somewhere for the list fill range and the linked cell. It's much easier and more robust to access these ranges in VBA than to try to get them from the listbox.

Speaking of reliability, the Form versions of all controls will be more reliable than their ActiveX analogues.